# Как в google Apps script получить несколько значений в формате .getTime из диапазона?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, таблицы

Нужна помощь. Пытаюсь организовать поиск строк по значению диапазона с датами в таблице гугл. Но критерий поиска это разница между текущей датой и датой из диапазона в 14 и более дней.

Пытался сделать так:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hvjaPuyYPQ1rm5Ew3Ig_dH1aQTu8kzYKEkebzsi6gw4');
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Лист1");
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Лист2");
const sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Лист3");
const millInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 *24;
let nowDate = new Date(sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue()).getTime();

function findRow(){
 new Date(sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues().getTime()
  .forEach(
    (row, i) => {
    if(((nowDate - row[0])/millInDay) >= 14 ) result(i+2);
 }));

}
function cresult(lastDate){
  console.log(lastDate);
}
```

Но валидатор пишет что функция `.getTime` не работает в таком формате. Пытался найти ответ на просторах сети, но не преуспел. Есть ли возможность реализовать такой поиск через .getTime или нужно копать в другую сторону. Заранее благодарен

Comment: В каком формате у вас записана дата в ячейке?

Comment: в формате даты dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вот это `sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues()` возвращает вам массив значений? Или это объект?

Comment: Да это массив с датами в котором необходимо произвести поиск. Кажется я понял один из вариантов решения, необходимо создать служебный столбец с датами в миллисикундах и искать у же по нему. А есть ли варианты без служебного столбца?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте, скрипт должен выглядеть так:

```js
// Допустим, что выборка вернула такой результат
// sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue() = 08.02.2023
const dateStringNow = '08.02.2023';
let nowDate = stringToDate(dateStringNow);

function stringToDate(dateString) {
    const dateValues = dateString.split('.');
    return new Date(dateValues[2], dateValues[1] - 1, dateValues[0], 0,0,0,0,0).getTime();
}

// Допустим это то что выбралось из sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues()
const datas = ['11.01.2023', '22.02.2018', '01.12.2021', '01.02.2023'];

function findRow() {
    datas.forEach((item, index) => {
        const colDate = stringToDate(item);
        if (nowDate - colDate > 86400000 * 14) {
            // Больше 14 дней
            console.log('Больше', item);
        } else {
            // Если меньше
            console.log('меньше', item)
        }
    })
}

findRow()
```

Код для google sheets(При условии что `sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues()` возвращает массив элементов):

```js
    let nowDate = stringToDate(sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue());

    function stringToDate(dateString) {
        const dateValues = dateString.split('.');
        return new Date(dateValues[2], dateValues[1] - 1, dateValues[0], 0,0,0,0,0).getTime();
    }

    function findRow() {
        sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues().forEach((item, index) => {
            const colDate = stringToDate(item);
            if (nowDate - colDate > 86400000 * 14) {
                // Больше 14 дней
                console.log('Больше', item);
            } else {
                // Если меньше
                console.log('меньше', item)
            }
        })
    }

    findRow()
```

P.S. Если вам надо взять дату "сегодня", то не обязательно выбирать дату из ячейки, можно сделать так `new Date().getTime()` и вернется текущее время

UPD: Т.к. возвращаемое значение и так имеет формат Date, можно отказаться от функции преобразования строки в дату:

```
let nowDate = sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue().getTime();

function findRow() {
    sheet3.getRange('B:B').getValues().forEach((item, index) => {        
        if (nowDate - item[0].getTime() > 86400000 * 14) {
            // Больше 14 дней
            console.log('Больше', item);
        } else {
            // Если меньше
            console.log('меньше', item)
        }
    })
}

findRow()
```

Comment: Не работает. Пишет TypeError: dateString.split is not a function. Про '''new Date().getTime()''' я в курсе но есть необходимость брать дату именно из ячейки. Для смены точки актуальности вручную при необходимости.

Comment: @Alt Какой тип данных передается в функцию? Перед dateString.split поставьте `console.log(dateString, typeof dateString)` и покажите

Comment: 00:07:11 Информация Thu Feb 09 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) 'object'
00:07:11 Ошибка TypeError: dateString.split is not a function stringToDate

Comment: @Alt Ну дык и где здесь заявленный формат dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: @Alt Обновил ответ. Попробуйте

Comment: 00:38:27
Ошибка
TypeError: item.getTime is not a function

Comment: @Alt Значит у вас еще и данные в цикл передаются в другом формате... Внутри цикла сделайте console.log(item, typeof item)` перед if

Comment: Я, кстати, уже несколько раз сталкивался с тем что внутри конструкций 'for' некоторые функции в apps script Не работают.

Comment: на всякий случай добавил 'let nowDate = sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue().getTime();
let nowDate1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue()
console.log(nowDate, typeof nowDate);
console.log(nowDate1, typeof nowDate1);' для проверки. В итоге: ' 00:51:31
Информация
1675890000000 'number'
00:51:31
Информация
Thu Feb 09 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) 'object'
00:51:31
Информация
[ Thu Dec 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) ] 'object' '

Comment: @Alt Так итого, item в цикле это что? Массив я как я понимаю. Вот последнее это результат вывода item?

Comment: Да, последнее это item. А доп проверки показывают что nowDate без getTime и item имеют одинаковый формат. Ну и то что .getTime в объявлении nowDate срабатывает как положено.

Comment: @Alt Тогда надо строчку `if (nowDate - item.getTime() > 86400000 * 14)` переделать в `if (nowDate - item[0].getTime() > 86400000 * 14)` - ответ скорректировал. У вас приходит не массив дат, а массив массивов, внутри которого лежат даты

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.

Comment: @Alt Если ответ вы принимаете, нажмите галочку слева от ответ "Принять ответ". Если ответ понравился, можно оставить голос за него