# Изменить формат даты в new Date в js

Tags: javascript

Задача: из гугл формы доставать данные ( название, дата начала, окончания ), на их основе создавать событие в гугл календаре. Задача выполнена, правда загвоздка: форма просит дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ., после чего в apps script мы создаем new Date и там уже формат ММ.ДД.ГГГГ.
Получается, если я выберу событие на 10 марта (10.03.2023) оно создается 3 октября уже

```
function myOnFormSubmit(e) { 
  var eventName = e.values[1]; 
  var eventDate = e.values[2]; 
  var startTime = e.values[3]; 
  var endTime = e.values[4]; 
  //var description = e.values[5]; 
   
  console.log(eventDate); 
  console.log(eventName); 
  console.log(startTime); 
  var startDate = new Date(); 
  startDate = new Date(eventDate + " " + startTime); 
  endDate = new Date( eventDate + " " + endTime); 
  var hehe = eventName + " " + startDate + " " + endDate; 
  var myCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("ni@gmail.com"); 
  myCal.createEvent( eventName, startDate, endDate); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail("ni@gmail.com", "hello", hehe); 
}
```

Comment: Разбейте `eventDate` с помощью `.split('.')` на массив и расставляйте значения в нужном вам порядке

Comment: Можно посмотреть как это делается [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474583/1474591#1474591) или вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494404/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-google-apps-script-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-gettime-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0/1494416#1494416)